# how to register view geometry made by MakeLine function?

Tags: geometry, spatialite

I am trying to to create a spatial view on my spatialite database.

```
        CREATE VIEW v2_pump_view AS
          SELECT pump.ROWID AS ROWID, pump.id AS pump_id,
             MakeLine(
                 start_node.the_geom, end_node.the_geom
                 ) AS the_geom
          FROM v2_pump AS pump
          , v2_connection AS start_node
          , v2_connection AS end_node
          where pump.connection_start_id = start_node.id
          AND pump.connection_end_id = end_node.id
        ;
```

Then, to register with the `views_geometry_columns`:

```
    INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns
    (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid, f_table_name, f_geometry_column)
    VALUES ('v2_pump_view', 'the_geom', 'ROWID',
        'v2_connection', 'the_geom');
```

Of course this doesn't work as the `connection` table has a point geometry. How I can register the line-geometry I made on the fly during the view creation by the `MakeLine`-function?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. A view can only refer to a real geometry column in the spatial table it is based on.

Comment: which can be empty? then i could add another column to connection, make it a line geometry and would use it to register the view...

Comment: Is there any reason not to just make a real table of line features?